# Builtin Mic and Webcam is not working properly for Safari (M1 2020)

Tags: safari, audio, video, microphone, webcam

My **builtin** Webcam and Mic are not working when I'm doing video or audio call in Safari.

Although I allow access to mix & camera, other people on the call only hear from my Mic is a "Beep Bop" sound and this image (below)  from my Webcam.

But I they work properly in Firefox, Chrome, Discord and other apps.

I tried to update my system but it didn't work.
I'v not got a clue about this problem.

MacBook Pro 2020 M1
OS: Monterey 12.6 (21G115)

[image]

Comment: Presumably it's an issue with Google Meets. What happens if you click on the buttons for sound and camera at the bottom?

Comment: No, it's happening with discord web and other sites also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the source of the issue.
This option was turned on.

[image]

To fix the issue you have to disable the `Use Mock Capture Device` option and turn on the `Allow Media Capture`

[image]